# Records missing from result of query, when joining with a cast and adding a where clause

Tags: postgresql

## Edit

Shortly after posting, I came up with this:

```
select
    c.id as c_id,
    c.category_name as category_name,
    case
        when p.id = 1 and cs.person_id is not null
            then true::text
        else false::text
    end is_subscribed
from category c
    full join category_subscription cs
      on c.id = cs.category_id
    full join person p
      on p.id = cs.person_id
```

Seems to work like this, but open to more suggestions

---

I'm having trouble properly structuring my query, to return all records. Instead, I just receive records that match a `is not null` clause, and I'm not sure why this is happening. I've tried all possible joins as well, so it's something else.

Suppose the following,

```
create table person(
  id serial primary key,
  person_name varchar(55)
);
create table category(
  id serial primary key,
  category_name varchar(55)
);
create table category_subscription(
  id serial primary key,
  category_id bigint references category(id),
  person_id bigint references person(id)
);
```

```
insert into person values (1, 'george');
insert into category values (10, 'homework'), (20, 'promotion');
insert into category_subscription values (100, 10, 1);
```

```
select
    c.id as c_id,
    c.category_name as category_name,
    (p.id is not null)::text as is_subscribed
from category c
full outer join category_subscription cs on c.id = cs.category_id
full outer join person p on p.id = cs.person_id
```

Now, this works all fine and dandy, returning all records with a `true` or `false` value for the `is_subscribed` column. However, the moment I append my where clause, only `true` records remain:

```
. . .
where p.person_name = 'george'
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix this? I need all `category_subscription` records for `george`, instead of blanket joining all `category_subscription` records on all `category` records.

For instance, if the `category_subscription` table is empty, the result of the query should be:

```
[
    {
        "c_id": 10,
        "category_name": "homework",
        "is_subscribed": false
    },
    {
        "c_id": 20,
        "category_name": "promotion",
        "is_subscribed": false
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

A `where` clause filters all the result rows, not only those from the respective table that go into the join. You'd want

```
select
    c.id as c_id,
    c.category_name as category_name,
    (p.id is not null)::text as is_subscribed
from category c
full outer join category_subscription cs on c.id = cs.category_id
full outer join (
    select *
    from person
    where person_name = 'george'
) as p on p.id = cs.person_id
```

or simpler

```
select
    c.id as c_id,
    c.category_name as category_name,
    (p.id is not null)::text as is_subscribed
from category c
full outer join category_subscription cs on c.id = cs.category_id
full outer join person p on p.id = cs.person_id and p.person_name = 'george'
```

Alternatively, don't use joins but just a subquery:

```
select
    c.id as c_id,
    c.category_name as category_name,
    exists(
        select *
        from category_subscription cs
        join person p on p.id = cs.person_id
        where c.id = cs.category_id
          and p.person_name = 'george'
    )::text as is_subscribed
from category c
```

This will also prevent getting duplicate categories if you accidentally inserted multiple subscriptions for the same person. To avoid that problem in the first place, get rid of the `id serial` column in `category_subscription` and make `(category_id, person_id)` a compound primary key.